# Creating and connecting sockets in c: Binding and connection error

Tags: c, sockets, networking, posix, unistd.h

This is my homework, and I've been looking at resources such as [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/), but I could not figure out how to fix binding fail error, and stop connection from hanging. 
Here's my code:

```
     /*
 * Assignment:
 * Write a program that optionally accepts an address and a port from the command line.
 * If there is no address/port on the command line, it should create a TCP socket and print the address
 * (i.e. server mode). If there is an address/port, it should connect to it (i.e. client mode).
 * Once the connections are set up, each side should enter a loop of receive, print what it received,
 * then send a message. The message should be “ping” from the client and “pong” from the server.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[100];
    char *msg_server = "pong";
    char *msg_client = "ping";

    ///server mode
    if (argc==1) { //if no address/port was given
        struct sockaddr_in me, other;
        int sockfd, new_sockfd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_sockfd
        printf("No address was given. Creating socket\n");
        //create a TCP socket
        sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) {
            printf("Error: Socket is not created\n");
            return -1;
        }
        memset(&me, 0, sizeof(me));
        me.sin_family = AF_INET;
        me.sin_port = htons(8000);
        me.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        printf("IP address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(me.sin_addr));
        //bind -> listen -> accept
        if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &me, sizeof(me)) < 0) {
            perror("bind");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (listen(sockfd, 3) < 0) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &other, (socklen_t *) sizeof(other))) < 0) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //loop of receive, printing received, sending a message
        while (1) {
            read( new_sockfd , buffer, 1000); //receive
            printf("%s\n",buffer ); //print
            send(new_sockfd, msg_server, strlen(msg_server), 0 ); //send
        }
    }
        ///Client mode
    else //there is an address/port
    {
        int sockfd, new_sockfd, port;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_sockfd
        struct sockaddr_in other;
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("Address entered: %s\nPort entered: %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
        sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) {
            printf("Error: Socket not created\n");
            return -1;
        }
        memset(&other, 0, sizeof(other));
        other.sin_family = AF_INET;
        other.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        other.sin_port = htons(port);

        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &other.sin_addr)<=0)
        {
            printf("Invalid address.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&other, sizeof(other)) < 0)
        {
            perror("connect");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //loop of receive, printing received, sending a message
        while (1) {
            send(new_sockfd, msg_client, strlen(msg_client), 0 ); //send
            read( new_sockfd , buffer, 1000); //receive
            printf("%s\n",buffer ); //print
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

Output in text:

> luna@DESKTOP-HLM1VNH:/mnt/c/users/dolne/clionprojects/lab9$ gcc lab9.c
>   -o lab9
>
> luna@DESKTOP-HLM1VNH:/mnt/c/users/dolne/clionprojects/lab9$ ./lab9
>
> No address was given. Creating socket
>
> IP address: 0.0.0.0
>
> bind: Address already in use
>
> luna@DESKTOP-HLM1VNH:/mnt/c/users/dolne/clionprojects/lab9$ ./lab9
>   127.0.0.1 8000
>
> Address entered: 127.0.0.1
>
> Port entered: 8000
>
> ^C

I've exited the hangings with ^C, or ^Z. If anyone could give me suggestions how to fix these errors, or even how to improve my code, I'd really appreciate it. This is my first time coding server and posix material.
update: I've included the function **perror()** for error handling to clarify errors.

Comment: Use `perror()` to give you a more detailed error msg to see why `bind` is failing.

Comment: Please do not post images, rather, select/copy/paste the text into your question

Comment: Also, don't use `^Z`. That will suspend the process but will not actually kill the process and will not release any ports it is holding on to. The `bind` problem is likely EADDRINUSE which means there is a process still holding the port. Kill that process.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if (sockfd <= 0) {
                printf("Error: Socket is not created\n");`  1) it is only an error when the returned value is <0.  ==0 is actually a valid socket.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` handles both those activities in a single call

Comment: both the server and the client need to know what port the server is listening on

Comment: There are a LOT of problems with the posted code.  Suggest separating the server and the client into separate functions so it is easy to distinguish between them

Comment: regarding; `int sockfd, new_sockfd, port;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_sockfd
            struct sockaddr_in other;
            port = atoi(argv[2]);`  the port should be a `short int` so there will be no conversion problem

Comment: regarding; `other.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`  in the client, this results in anyone can talk to your client.  Suggest using: `other.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( "127.0.0.1" );`

Comment: regarding: `while (1) {
                read( new_sockfd , buffer, 1000); //receive
                printf("%s\n",buffer ); //print
                send(new_sockfd, msg_client, strlen(msg_client), 0 ); //send
            }` in the client, the client has to contact the server, so the client needs to transmit first

Comment: if you want to have the server be able to handle more than one client connected, then there needs to be a statement similar to: `setsockopt( serverSock, reuseaddress, (int)1 );`  Don't blindly copy this statement, check the actual syntax and naming of the option.   Suggest a similar statement in the client

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `gcc lab9.c -o lab9`  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. Suggest using: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 lab9.c -o lab9`

Answer (score 2):

Both client and server are doing `read` *before* `send`, so they are *both* initially waiting for a message that will never arrive.

One of them *has* to go *first* and send the message.

From:

> The message should be “ping” from the client and “pong” from the server.

Implies that the client should send the first message. This means the client should do: `send` and then do `read` (vs. both doing `read` and then `send`).

But, neither checks the return value from `read`, so neither will exit if the other closes the socket.

Also, the server, after doing `accept`, should do a `fork` and have the loop done in the child. Otherwise, one and *only* one client could connect to the server at a given time.